# Why is a directory added to my PATH?

Tags: bash, path, bashrc

I am having a very weird issue with my `PATH` variable. In particular, at some point `/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin` is added and I would like it not to be.

The first thing I did was to check `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, and `/etc/environment` to see if any of them were setting it, but they were not.

Next I thought perhaps a stealthy script chain might be doing so, so I ran:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>log
```

To see if it would shed some light. To my amazement, `/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin` wasn't there. To see if this was replicable in a simpler environment, I just ran a naked `bash` from the prompt. However in this `bash`, `PATH` once again contains `/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin`.

The scary thing is that the same path exists in my root user shell too; however, it doesn't happen if I don't run X. I thought it could have to do with the X configuration scripts, but none of them modified `PATH`. I also thought it could be in the configuration of my terminal (termite), but it doesn't do so either. Frankly, at this point, I'm at a loss.

Can anybody tell me how I can stop this path from being added to my `PATH` variable?

FOLLOWUP:

Overnight I ran a `find . -type f -print0 | parallel --progress --null -L 100 -m -j 4 grep -I 'hardening-wrapper'` to see what it would find. Overall it found the following matches:

- `.bash_history` because I've been running a bunch of commands that include it
- `./csassignments/ece454/thrift-0.10.0` contains my thrift installation for a course I took on distributed computation. In the 'tutorial_client' it sets and exports the PATH in 'relink_command'. I suspect this is because my PATH contained it when I installed thrift?
- The source code of GNU binutils and GCC that I use to build cross compilers both contain logs that print PATH. Like above I suspect they just read what my path was.
- A bunch of CMake projects I've built from source (llvm) seem to have also read my old PATH

As far as I can tell, none of those is being loaded automatically. And the only one that actually exports the path it modifies is the thrift tutorial client which I haven't touched since I took the course.

Comment: Are you sure `/etc/profile.d/hardening-wrapper.sh` doesn't exist?

Comment: Yep. I even ran `grep -RnH "hardening" /etc/profile.d` -- no results.

Comment: Are you running Arch Linux?

Comment: You didn't mention that you checked `/etc/bash.bashrc`. And what if you do `bash --norc` or `bash --noprofile`? Finally, you could do `grep -r hardening /etc` to find more traces.

Comment: Both `bash --norc` and `bash --noprofile` contain the hardening wrapper. `grep -r hardening /etc` actually returned 0 results.

Comment: you could `find . -type f -print0 | parallel --progress --null -L 100 -m -j 4 grep -l 'PATH=.*PATH' ` as well?  # -l = -L (but not caps), and will list all files that try to set PATH ? or maybe a larger regexp: `PATH.*PATH` (to also match : let PATH .... and  env PATH ... )

Answer (score 1):

> The scary thing is that the same path exists in my root user shell
>   too, however it doesn't happen if I don't run X. I thought it could
>   have to do with the X configuration scripts, but none of them modified
>   PATH.

Actually, you claim it only gets set when X is started, this "usually" means it is set by X somehow. Sadly, you do not say which desktop environment you use, but this is good, because it means that I have to come up with a generic answer.

You do not tell us which X configuration files you checked. The following set environment variables for gui applications:

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc 
~/.xinitrc
/etc/xprofile
~/.xprofile
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables

Also have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile

If all this does not help, it would be nice to know which GNU/Linux distribution you use with which desktop environment.

Comment: Those are exactly the files I checked (though I lack the xprofiles). I am using Arch Linux with i3-gaps, no DE. Still none of them modified the environment variables.